# Powershell, selenium, javascript automation click on link

Tags: javascript, powershell, selenium

Trying to automate Powershell, selenium on Chrome for a link that contains javascript.

I can open a link from the same page which doesn't have javascript in it but I can't get the javascript link to open.

This is the link text I get when I inspect it on Chrome.

```
<a href="javascript:ShowMnt()" title="Perform the Administrative Functions" class="fade link-button">
                <i class="fas fa-tasks"></i>Maintenance        </a>
```

This is the code I am using on the XPath that I get for the link.

```
$ChromeDriver.FindElement([OpenQa.Selenium.By]::XPath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/fieldset[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/a')).Click()
```

This is the ERROR:
MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "FindElement" with "1" argument(s): "no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/fieldset[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/a"}

Can javascripts link be launched this way?
I have also tried using other links that have javascript in them on the same page and get a similar issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: According to the error message, the problem is not caused by the javascript, but by an incorrect XPath expression. Try to reduce the XPath to the parent element(s) until you have narrowed down the problem. Personally I would simplify the XPath to this: `//a[title='Perform the Administrative Functions']`.

Comment: Thank you.
Tried the suggestion and get a similar error.
MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "FindElement" with "1" argument(s): "no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[title='Perform the Administrative Functions']"}
I have also tried other method instead of Xpath but alway get an error about no such element.

Comment: A little mistake. Try `//a[@title='Perform the Administrative Functions']`